# Passing value from a jsp page to js file and reflects the changes in jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

If I enter value 10 in text area then it will pop up an alert and return square of the entered value but not getting it.

```js
function g() {
  var a = document.getElementsById("number").value;
  if (a == 10) {
    alert(a * a);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="g.js">
</script>
<form onsubmit="return g()">
  Enter No:<input type="text" id="number" name="number" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="c" />
</form>
```

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools. Look at the console. **Read the error message**. The function is called `getElementById` (**singular** not plural).

Comment: @Quentin I made changes but still not working. If I add the js code in same page as form page it is working but trying with separate js file and add that js file to the form page like I am trying to do, it is not working. I can not figure out why?

Comment: If fixing that typo doesn't solve the problem then check the network tab. Look at the request for the JS file. Make sure the JS file is being returned. And if it isn't, look up how to serve static files with whatever webserver you are using.

Comment: I am using local apache server.
what do you mean by network tab and where to look for?

Comment: See my initial comment where I said "Open your browser's developer tools"

Comment: When you say "local apache server" do you mean "Apache Tomcat"? AFAIK Apache HTTPD (which is what people usually mean when they just say Apache) doesn't support JSP.

Comment: the answer to your previous server related question.
yes, I am using apache tomcat in eclipse.
I did some configuration for jsp dynamic project so i can run both jsp and js files.

Comment: I tried that console thing you mentioned before error is 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement games.js:6

if(isNaN(quantity.value))
{
alert('ID should be in numeric value');
document.getElementById('quantity').value="";
quantity.focus();
return false; // error
}

but this was my previous code of checking for numbers, it is not showing my new code what i edited in js file. 
i do not know why i tried closing and reopening the server and browser as well.

Comment: @Quentin It seems to be something wrong with my chrome browser i think, i tried with mozilla and it is working fine.
thanks for the help man.